# Валидация Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Могу ли я с помощью валидации в контроллере задать максимальное значение числа? Т.к. `'amount' => 'max:2'` ограничивает кол-во символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно, вот таким образом: `'amount' => 'integer|max:2'`